# Fedora + KDE not detecting TV after it is turned off

Tags: fedora, kde, nvidia, display-settings

I'm using Fedora 39 + KDE On Nvidia drivers. GPU is 4090.
My TV is connected to the computer and is detected properly after a restart.

But if I disable it in "Display Configuration", and then turn off the TV, sleep the computer, and then resume, the TV will not be detected.

Restarting again will fix this, but is tedious.

Is there a command to force re-enumerate all connected displays?